# How this part of code is working

Tags: c#, ienumerator

UPD.
Hello,
I know how code below is working. I know that cross, and circle are pointing to Cross(), and Circle() method. But I am still filling little confuse with this part of code. Can you explain it for me?

```
public GameMoves()
            {
                cross = Cross();
                circle = Circle();
            }
```

---

All code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                GameMoves game = new GameMoves();
                IEnumerator enumerator = game.Cross();
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    enumerator = (IEnumerator)enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }

        public class GameMoves
        {
            private IEnumerator cross;
            private IEnumerator circle;

            public GameMoves()
            {
                cross = Cross();
                circle = Circle();
            }

            private int move = 0;
            public IEnumerator Cross()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X, step {0}", move);
                    move++;
                    if (move > 9)
                        yield break;
                    yield return circle;
                }
            }

            public IEnumerator Circle()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("O, step {0}", move);
                    move++;
                    if (move > 9)
                        yield break;
                    yield return cross;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [*This* is cod](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cod) -- Sorry, couldn't resist. :-)

Comment: You have unmatched brackets, are you missing code? Also you seem to be missing your e's off the word code?

Comment: @stakx: And the OP's "cod" sure smells fishy to me ;)

Comment: I recommend that you refactor your cod to be based on the WhiteFish library. This is just my personal preference, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Cross` and `Circle` are generators. They return a sequence of `object`s by means of an `IEnumerable`. That is, you could write:

```
foreach (var cross in Cross())  // works with Circle, also
{
    // ...
}
```

And on every loop iteration, the next element to be returned is generated inside the `Cross` or `Circle` method. Those methods don't execute all at a time, instead each time a `yield return` statement is reached, program execution will continue in the calling code (the `foreach` loop), and the code inside the generator is only resumed when the next item is needed.

---

<sup>**P.S.:** Before my internet connection broke down for some hours, I had also wanted to comment on the strange fact that your generators keeps returning references to themselves via `yield return`. That doesn't really make sense to me, to be honest; I've never seen that kind of code and I wonder if it actually does something useful?</sup>

Comment: This code is example from book. It is illustrate how operator yield is working. But for some reason It makes me confuse. That is why I put my question.

Comment: If that's from a textbook, and the other code examples in it are like that, you should consider getting rid of the book. It's not difficult coming up with better examples of `yield return` and `yield break`. A very basic example is this: **(1)** Define an iterator: `IEnumerable<int> Range(int from, int to) { for (int i = from; i < to; i++) yield return i; }` -- **(2)** Example usage of the iterator: `foreach (int i in Range(1, 10)) { Console.WriteLine(i); }`